# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes Error for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, macos, operands

I have looked through the other answers for Operand errors and none seem to fit this example.
The mathematics/equation works, either coding in X values or importing from the DataFrame.
Using the same equation in an np.where expression causes the operand error.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

data= pd.read_csv('miniDF.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X','Z'])
df['y']=df['Z']*0.01


df['y']=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                       +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X']))

print(df)

df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                      +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X']),8,9))

print(df)
```

The values in my Dataframe, the output from the first print(df) and the error are as follows.

```
      X     Z           y
0   1.4     1  999.999293
1   2.0  2000  380.275104
2   3.0     3  159.114194
3   4.0     4   91.481930
4   5.0     5   69.767368
5   6.0     6   63.030212
6   7.0    70   59.591631
7   8.0     8   56.422723
8   9.0     9   54.673108
9  10.0    10   55.946732
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/willhutchins/Desktop/minitest.py", line 17, in <module>
df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1229, in wrapper
res = na_op(values, other)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1115, in na_op
result = method(y)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (3,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply a misplaced Parenthesis as answered here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046213/complex-curve-equation-giving-error-in-np-where-usage][1]

Corrected code is:

```
df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                      +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X'])),8,9)
```