# Complex curve equation giving error in np.where usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos, where-clause

I have looked through the other answers for Operand errors and none seem to fit this example. The mathematics/equation works, either coding in X values or importing from the DataFrame. Using the same equation in an np.where expression causes the operand error.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

data= pd.read_csv('miniDF.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X','Z'])
df['y']=df['Z']*0.01


df['y']=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                       +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X']))

print(df)

df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                      +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X']),8,9))

print(df)
```

The values in my Dataframe, the output from the first print(df) and the error are as follows.

```
      X     Z           y
0   1.4     1  999.999293
1   2.0  2000  380.275104
2   3.0     3  159.114194
3   4.0     4   91.481930
4   5.0     5   69.767368
5   6.0     6   63.030212
6   7.0    70   59.591631
7   8.0     8   56.422723
8   9.0     9   54.673108
9  10.0    10   55.946732
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/willhutchins/Desktop/minitest.py", line 17, in <module>
df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1229, in wrapper
res = na_op(values, other)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1115, in na_op
result = method(y)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (3,)
```

Why does the equation work as a stand-alone item but not work when used in np.where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let:

```
expr = 14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)+1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X'])
```

then you'll find out that your code is:

```
df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(expr,8,9))
```

The `shape` of `df['Z']` is `(10,)`, which means it is a one-dimensional `pandas.Series` object which has `10` rows. However, `(expr,8,9)` is a simple `tuple` which has 3 items (`expr` is indeed a 10-row `pandas.Series` however).

That's why the hint is `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (3,)` , since `numpy` doesn't know how to compare a **10**-row `pandas.Series` with a **3**-item `tuple`.

Check your equation again and get it modified to meet your needs.

**UPDATE:**

According to the comment, the `8` and `9` are two arguments to `np.where(condition,x,y)` as the `x` and `y`. But you put them in the `expr` after `df['Z']>=` by mistake, which makes the `>=` operator compares a `pandas.Series`'s with a `tuple`, but not two `pandas.Series`.

Just move the last parentheses and the code will work well:

```
df['y']=np.where(df['Z']>=(14.6413819224756*(df['X']**0.5)+64.4092780704338*(np.log(df['X'])**-2)
                      +1675.7498523727*(np.exp(-df['X']))+3.07221083927051*np.cos(df['X'])),8,9)
```

The result should be:

```
     X     Z  y
0   1.4     1  9
1   2.0  2000  8
2   3.0     3  9
3   4.0     4  9
4   5.0     5  9
5   6.0     6  9
6   7.0    70  8
7   8.0     8  9
8   9.0     9  9
9  10.0    10  9
```

**UPDATE 2:**

To do `np.where` while two conditions are met, or to say, an `and` operation, just use `np.where((condition1) & (conditions),x,y)`. For example:

```
df['foo']=np.where((df['Z']>3) & (df['Z']<100),True,False)
```

Note, **the parentheses here before and after `&` is necessary**. You'll get this with your data:

```
      X     Z           y    foo
0   1.4     1  999.999293  False
1   2.0  2000  380.275104  False
2   3.0     3  159.114194  False
3   4.0     4   91.481930   True
4   5.0     5   69.767368   True
5   6.0     6   63.030212   True
6   7.0    70   59.591631   True
7   8.0     8   56.422723   True
8   9.0     9   54.673108   True
9  10.0    10   55.946732   True
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use np.where. I thought the last two digits,8 & 9 in this case, were the 'what to do based on the results of the equation'. i.e.  if False put '8' in df['y'] column for that row, if True, put 9 instead.

Comment: @WillH No, if that's what you want, you just put the last parentheses after `np.cos(df['X'])` but not after `8,9`.

Comment: @WillH I've just edited my answer, this is just a very small mistake - you just put the partentheses in the wrong position. All the question is the error message maybe a little strange for you, so I explained that.

Comment: That has fixed it. As you say, simple error in Parentheses placement. All new to me and I'm having to learn fast.

Comment: Quick additional question @C.K.  If I want to do this when two conditions are met, what is the syntax? i.e. df['y']=np.where1 And np.where2, 'Yes','No'

Comment: @WillH try `np.where((condition1) & (conditions),x,y)`, I have updated the answer.